# Prepending a div to another div dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to have it when I click on "Add Exercise", the a new collapsible bootstrap div will be added inside my card div. each time the button is clicked. I have been trying for a while now and reading up other questions on here but I cannot seem to get it to work.

I added my code to jsfiddle. Cany anyone help me get this working finally?

https://jsfiddle.net/dmngpo8e/4/

```js
$('input[name="queue"]').click(function() {
  $("<div class='panel-group'><div class='panel panel-default'><div class='panel-heading'><h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' href='#collapse1'>Collapsible panel</a></h4></div><div id='collapse1' class='panel-collapse collapse'><div class='panel-body'>Panel Body</div><div class='panel-footer'>Panel Footer</div></div></div></div>").html('item').appendTo('card');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<input class="btn teach_edit_header_buttons" style="font-family:Helvetica" name="queue" type="submit" value="Add Exercise">


<div class="card" style="padding:10px;background-color:#c7e0fc;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.appendTo('card');` should be `.appendTo('.card');` .. and by use `html('item')` before it it'll just change the whole div html with word `item`  so you need to remove `html('item')`

Comment: Thank you, and to the others who replied just after! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try by adding dot(class selector) before `card`

```js
$('input[name="queue"]').click(function() {
  $("<div class='panel-group'>" +
    "<div class='panel panel-default'>" +
    "<div class='panel-heading'>" +
    "<h4 class='panel-title'>" +
    "<a data-toggle='collapse' href='#collapse1'>Collapsible panel</a>" +
    "</h4>" +
    "</div>" +
    "<div id='collapse1' class='panel-collapse collapse'>" +
    "<div class='panel-body'>Panel Body</div>" +
    "<div class='panel-footer'>Panel Footer</div>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>").html('item').appendTo('.card');
})
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->



<input class="btn teach_edit_header_buttons" style="font-family:Helvetica" name="queue" type="submit" value="Add Exercise">


<div class="card" style="padding:10px;background-color:#c7e0fc;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @bkr and @Mohamed-Yousef already mentioned, you had a few issues with your code:

1. Remove `.html('item')` as it's overwriting the collapsible bootstrap div.
2. You were missing a dot in `.appendTo('card')`, should be `.appendTo('.card')`.
3. Also, for the collapsible button to work after you add it, you also need Bootstrap's JS file, otherwise the collapsible bootstrap divs won't work (see code below).

```js
$('input[name="queue"]').click(function() {
  $("<div class='panel-group'><div class='panel panel-default'><div class='panel-heading'><h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' href='#collapse1'>Collapsible panel</a></h4></div><div id='collapse1' class='panel-collapse collapse'><div class='panel-body'>Panel Body</div><div class='panel-footer'>Panel Footer</div></div></div></div>").appendTo('.card');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<input class="btn teach_edit_header_buttons" style="font-family:Helvetica" name="queue" type="submit" value="Add Exercise">


<div class="card" style="padding:10px;background-color:#c7e0fc;">
</div>
```